# for_each alternative for terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-modules

I have the following snippet of code for subnet groups for rds:

```
data "aws_subnets" "example" {
   filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
   }
   filter {
   name = "tag:tier"
   values = ["app"]
   }
}

data "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.example.ids)
  id = each.value
}


resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet_groups" {
  subnet_ids = data.aws_subnets.example.ids
}
```

I was following the documentation for terraform but it's failing for `Invalid for_each argument`.

Full error :

`data.aws_subnets.example.ids` is a list of string, known only after apply

The for_each set includes values derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until after apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instance of this resource.

When working with unknown values in for_each it's better to use a map value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where only the values contain apply-time results.

Alternatively, you could se the -target planning option to first apply only the resources tht the for_each value depends on and then apply a second time to fully converge

I was wondering if someone used a map or know alternative how to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you show the full error? just copying and pasting this code as you have written it and providing my own subnet filter works and creates a db_subnet_resource group with the list of subnet ids

Comment: this seems to fail for when creating it for a secondary region

Comment: You have to use `-target` as explained in the error message first.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shared here it seems like `var.vpc_id` must be a value Terraform doesn't know yet, which would happen if the corresponding VPC were being planned for creation at the same time because a VPC ID hasn't been allocated yet and in turn there won't yet be any subnets in that VPC to query.

If that's true then what you have here is an example of the problem of having both `resource` blocks and `data` blocks in your configuration which refer to the same remote object. If a different module of this configuration is also the one responsible for *managing* the VPC and the subnets (using `resource` blocks) then you should typically not have `data` blocks referring to that VPC or subnet anywhere in your configuration.

Instead, you can pass information about the subnets from the module that declared them into this module that will use them. For example:

```
variable "vpc" {
  type = object({
    id = string
  })
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    id = string
  }))
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "subnet_groups" {
  subnet_ids = [for s in var.subnets : s.id]
}
```

You haven't shared the source code for the module that's calling this one so I can't show a concrete example of that but here's a contrived example showing how passing a VPC and a map of subnets into the above module might work:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = ["a", "b", "c"]

  # ...
}

module "child" {
  source = "../modules/child" # (this is the module I showed above)

  vpc     = aws_vpc.example
  subnets = aws_subnet_example
}
```

Terraform will make sure that the `vpc` value is a single object with an ID and that the `subnets` value is a map of objects that each have an ID, which is true for `aws_vpc` and `aws_subnet`.

By passing in the actual resource objects rather than trying to re-fetch their data using a `data` block, you get both some improved efficiency (no need to re-fetch data Terraform already has in memory anyway) and you give Terraform a better description of the relationships between the objects, so it can determine automatically what order the operations need to happen in.

---

I kept the above declarations minimal but if your module needs to use other properties of the subnets, such as their CIDR blocks, then you can add additional required attributes to the type constraints of the variables:

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    id         = string
    cidr_block = string
  }))
}
```

Any `aws_subnet` resource instance will match the object type constraint in the above because that resource type has both `id` and `cidr_block` attributes that are each of string type.